# Get the total value of the matching array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my current array

```
0:{modelNumber: "123456789", balance: { amount:1000, currency:"EUR" }}
1:{modelNumber: "987654321", balance: { amount:2000, currency:"EUR" }}
2:{modelNumber: "322353466", balance: { amount:1500, currency:"GBP" }}
3:{modelNumber: "892347522", balance: { amount:1000, currency:"USD" }}
4:{modelNumber: "931883113", balance: { amount:3000, currency:"INR" }}
5:{modelNumber: "854300564", balance: { amount:2500, currency:"GBP" }}
6:{modelNumber: "931883113", balance: { amount:3000, currency:"INR" }}
7:{modelNumber: "854300564", balance: { amount:3500, currency:"USD" }}
```

I'm trying to return a new array, with each currency and the total value for each currency.

Like below return the total amount for each currency in the array above

```
0:{currency: "EUR", totalAmount: 3500}
1:{currency: "GBP", totalAmount: 5000}
2:{currency: "USD", totalAmount: 4500}
3:{currency: "INR", totalAmount: 6000}
```

My approach initially:

```
//the current array
let theInitialArray = state.vehicle;

const results = theInitialArray.reduce((accumalator, current) => {
    const { currency } = current.balance;
    if (accumalator[currency]) {
        accumalator[currency].push(current);
        return accumalator;
    }
    accumalator[currency] = [current];
    return accumalator;     
}, {});

let frank =  Object.keys(results)
let jim = [];
let expectedOutput = theInitialArray.filter((x) => {
    for (let i=0; i < frank.length; i++) {
        if (x.balance.currency === frank[i]) {
            jim.push({'currency': frank[i], 'amount': x.balance.amount});
        }
    }
});
console.log('expectedOutput', expectedOutput)
return expectedOutput
```

Comment: Would you also consider `{ "EUR": 3000, "GBP": 4000, "USD": 4500, "INR": 6000 }` as output? It would hold the exact same information and would be much easier to work with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a `O(n)` approach of getting that output:

1. You first define a empty object `tempObj` which will be used to store the `currency` and `totalAmount` value as a object based on the `currency` key
2. Then, if this `currency` key is defined in the `tempObj` you will simply add the `amount` with the `totalAmount` for an existing object.
3. Else you will create a object with the `amount` as `totalAmount`, `currency` as `key` of `tempObj` and `currency` as `currency` of the item in `forEach` loop
4. Finally you will need to do `Object.values(tempObj)` so that we get the object values and ignore the keys of `tempObj` to get the desired result.

```js
var arr = [{modelNumber: "123456789", balance: { amount:1000, currency:"EUR" }},
{modelNumber: "987654321", balance: { amount:2000, currency:"EUR" }},
{modelNumber: "322353466", balance: { amount:1500, currency:"GBP" }},
{modelNumber: "892347522", balance: { amount:1000, currency:"USD" }},
{modelNumber: "931883113", balance: { amount:3000, currency:"INR" }},
{modelNumber: "854300564", balance: { amount:2500, currency:"GBP" }},
{modelNumber: "931883113", balance: { amount:3000, currency:"INR" }},
{modelNumber: "854300564", balance: { amount:3500, currency:"USD" }}];

var tempObj = {};
arr.forEach((obj)=>{
  if(tempObj[obj.balance.currency]){
    tempObj[obj.balance.currency].totalAmount += obj.balance.amount
  } else {
    tempObj[obj.balance.currency] = {
      currency: obj.balance.currency,
      totalAmount : obj.balance.amount
    }
  }
});
var resArray = Object.values(tempObj);
console.log(resArray);
```

Comment: This wonderful ,I was thinking the same way but I do many steps after the forEach but you mange all in single loop , I can't do more than upvote

Comment: Nice. It would be even easier to simply return `{
  "EUR": 3000,
  "GBP": 4000,
  "USD": 4500,
  "INR": 6000
}` An array of dicts is rarely the best data format.

Answer (score 8):

You can [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate the data. If a currency doesn't exist in the accumulator (`r` in the reduce callback), initialize it. Add the current amount, to the currency amount in the accumulator. Get an array of currencies using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const data = [{"modelNumber":"123456789","balance":{"amount":1000,"currency":"EUR"}},{"modelNumber":"987654321","balance":{"amount":2000,"currency":"EUR"}},{"modelNumber":"322353466","balance":{"amount":1500,"currency":"GBP"}},{"modelNumber":"892347522","balance":{"amount":1000,"currency":"USD"}},{"modelNumber":"931883113","balance":{"amount":3000,"currency":"INR"}},{"modelNumber":"854300564","balance":{"amount":2500,"currency":"GBP"}},{"modelNumber":"931883113","balance":{"amount":3000,"currency":"INR"}},{"modelNumber":"854300564","balance":{"amount":3500,"currency":"USD"}}];

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { balance }) => {
  const { amount, currency } = balance;
  if(!r[currency]) r[currency] = { currency, amount: 0 };
  
  r[currency].amount += amount;
  
  return r;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with  [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and  [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const data = [
    {modelNumber: "123456789", balance: { amount:1000, currency:"EUR" }},
    {modelNumber: "987654321", balance: { amount:2000, currency:"EUR" }},
    {modelNumber: "322353466", balance: { amount:1500, currency:"GBP" }},
    {modelNumber: "892347522", balance: { amount:1000, currency:"USD" }},
    {modelNumber: "931883113", balance: { amount:3000, currency:"INR" }},
    {modelNumber: "854300564", balance: { amount:2500, currency:"GBP" }},
    {modelNumber: "931883113", balance: { amount:3000, currency:"INR" }},
    {modelNumber: "854300564", balance: { amount:3500, currency:"USD" }}
];

const grouped = data.reduce((o, { balance: { amount:a, currency:c } }) =>
   ({...o, [c]: (o[c] || 0) + a }), {});

const result = Object.keys(grouped).map(currency =>
    ({currency, totalAmount: grouped[currency] }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to reduce the values you have and them map them into the format you require:

```js
const values = [
  {modelNumber: "123456789", balance: { amount:1000, currency:"EUR" }},
  {modelNumber: "987654321", balance: { amount:2000, currency:"EUR" }},
  {modelNumber: "322353466", balance: { amount:1500, currency:"GBP" }},
  {modelNumber: "892347522", balance: { amount:1000, currency:"USD" }},
  {modelNumber: "931883113", balance: { amount:3000, currency:"INR" }},
  {modelNumber: "854300564", balance: { amount:2500, currency:"GBP" }},
  {modelNumber: "931883113", balance: { amount:3000, currency:"INR" }},
  {modelNumber: "854300564", balance: { amount:3500, currency:"USD" }},
];

const results = values.reduce((prev, curr) => ({
  ...prev,
  [curr.balance.currency]: (prev[curr.balance.currency] || 0) + curr.balance.amount
}), {})

const inCorrectFormat = Object.keys(results).map(key => ({
  currency: key,
  totalAmount: results[key]
}))

console.dir(inCorrectFormat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and render the wanted array of `currency`/`totalAmount` pairs as new objects.

```js
var data = [{ modelNumber: "123456789", balance: { amount: 1000, currency: "EUR" } }, { modelNumber: "987654321", balance: { amount: 2000, currency: "EUR" } }, { modelNumber: "322353466", balance: { amount: 1500, currency: "GBP" } }, { modelNumber: "892347522", balance: { amount: 1000, currency: "USD" } }, { modelNumber: "931883113", balance: { amount: 3000, currency: "INR" } }, { modelNumber: "854300564", balance: { amount: 2500, currency: "GBP" } }, { modelNumber: "931883113", balance: { amount: 3000, currency: "INR" } }, { modelNumber: "854300564", balance: { amount: 3500, currency: "USD" } }],
    result = Array.from(
        data.reduce((m, { balance: { amount, currency } }) =>
            m.set(currency, (m.get(currency) || 0) + amount), new Map),
        ([currency, totalAmount]) => ({ currency, totalAmount })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses two arrays and pushes the unique names of the currencies in one(currencies) and the objects in another (result).

```
a = [{modelNumber: "123456789", balance: { amount:1000, currency:"EUR" }}, {modelNumber: "987654321", balance: { amount:2000, currency:"EUR" }},{modelNumber: "322353466", balance: { amount:1500, currency:"GBP" }},{modelNumber: "892347522", balance: { amount:1000, currency:"USD" }},{modelNumber: "931883113", balance: { amount:3000, currency:"INR" }},{modelNumber: "854300564", balance: { amount:2500, currency:"GBP" }},{modelNumber: "931883113", balance: { amount:3000, currency:"INR" }},{modelNumber: "854300564", balance: { amount:3500, currency:"USD" }}]

let currencies = [], result = [];
a.map((v)=>{
  let {currency, amount} = v.balance;
  if(!currencies.includes(currency)){
    currencies.push(currency);
    result.push({currency, totalAmount:amount});
  }else{
    result[currencies.findIndex(vv=>vv===currency)].totalAmount+=amount;
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution with native array methods [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
const res = arr
  // map to currency
  .map(i => i.balance.currency)
  // get unique currency
  .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i)
  // map to result
  .map((i, a) => ({
    currency: i,
    totalAmount: calcTotalAmount(i)
  }));

// calculate amount
function calcTotalAmount(currency) {
  return (
    arr
      // filter to current curency
      .filter(i => i.balance.currency === currency)
      // reduce to number
      .reduce((accum, i) => accum + i.balance.amount, 0)
  );
}
```